# Concurrent use of multiple Python versions

Tags: python, debian, debian-buster

I have a script (speedtest-cli) that requires Python2, but need to use Python3 for Ansible.

Through update-alternatives I've set "auto mode" and Python3.  I suppose in my naivity I had somehow expected this would automatically use Python2 for the script that requires that, but it doesn't work.

What is the best way to deal with this?

Debian Buster

**Update 1:** Tried the suggestion by furas. It didn't change anything, the script still throws the same errors ....

```
rcd@gw:~$ python2 speedtest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/speedtest-cli", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3019, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3003, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3032, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 655, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 963, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 849, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'speedtest-cli==1.0.0' distribution was not found and is required by the application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "speedtest.py", line 12, in <module>
    ping = ping[0].replace(',', '.')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Note how it addresses /usr/lib/python3 although I run python2 ....

```
rcd@gw:~$ type python2
python2 is hashed (/usr/bin/python2)
rcd@gw:~$ type python
python is /usr/bin/python
rcd@gw:~$ type python3
python3 is /usr/bin/python3
rcd@gw:~$ ls -al /usr/bin/python*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      24 Jun 10 19:03 /usr/bin/python -> /etc/alternatives/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Jan 24  2017 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3779512 Sep 26  2018 /usr/bin/python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Jan 20  2017 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.5
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4751184 Sep 27  2018 /usr/bin/python3.5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 Sep 27  2018 /usr/bin/python3.5-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.5-config
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4751184 Sep 27  2018 /usr/bin/python3.5m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      34 Sep 27  2018 /usr/bin/python3.5m-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.5m-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Jan 20  2017 /usr/bin/python3-config -> python3.5-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      10 Jan 20  2017 /usr/bin/python3m -> python3.5m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      17 Jan 20  2017 /usr/bin/python3m-config -> python3.5m-config
```

Then I tried with virtualenv ....

```
rcd@gw:~$ virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 venv2.7
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2.7
New python executable in /home/rcd/venv2.7/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in /home/rcd/venv2.7/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pkg_resources, pip, wheel...done.
rcd@gw:~$ source venv2.7/bin/activate
```

Run with python2.7, exactly same result ...

```
(venv2.7) rcd@gw:~$ python2 speedtest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/speedtest-cli", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3019, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3003, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3032, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 655, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 963, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 849, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'speedtest-cli==1.0.0' distribution was not found and is required by the application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "speedtest.py", line 12, in <module>
    ping = ping[0].replace(',', '.')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don't know what's going on here, no matter what I do it seems to want to run with Python3 ....

Comment: Create a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) for speedtest-cli and run your script from the python 2 environment. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54782163/use-python2-7-in-venv-where-python3-is-default-python) as well.

Comment: you can run manually `python2 script.py` and `python3 other_script.py`. OR inside script use `sheband` for this `#!/bin/env python2` or `#!/bin/env python3` and set `chmod +x script.py` to make it executable and then it will use `shebang` to execute script.

Answer (score 0):

Standard method is to use `shebang` (`#!`) in first line of script to inform system what program it has to use to execute this script - `Python 2`, `Python 3`, `bash`, `perl`, `PHP`, etc.

```
#!/full/path/to/python2

#!/full/path/to/python2.7

#!/full/path/to/python3

#!/full/path/to/python3.6

#!/full/path/to/python3.7
```

or more universal and more popular

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

#!/usr/bin/env python3

#!/usr/bin/env python3.6

#!/usr/bin/env python3.7
```

And script has to be executable so it need `chmod +x script.py`

---

Of course you can always execute it manually

```
python2   script.py

python2.7 script.py

python3   script.py

python3.6 script.py

python3.7 script.py
```

Comment: All of the above all throw errors referring to python3.

Comment: what error ? What do you get with `python2 -V` , `python3 -V`,etc.  You should have different names for different versions (at least I have it on Linux Mint 19.3 based on Ubuntu, which is based on Debian). And this way you could run different version. And maybe you shouldn't set alternative but keep it as it was before.

Comment: do you get error when you use `/full/path/to/python2` and `/full/path/to/python3` ? it should run correct version - if you didn't replace versions.

Comment: it seems you messed up with versions. When you run `python2` then it show in error `/usr/lib/python3` and it means it uses `python3` . And now even `virtualenv` uses this wrong `python2` and you get error even inside `virtualenv`. Check what you get with `python2 -V` - it should show what version it is.

Comment: BTW: you run `speedtest.py` but it shows problem in `/usr/bin/speedtest-cli`. What do you have in `speedtest.py` ? If you run `os.system("/usr/bin/speedtest-cli")` then it will use python defined as `#!` inside `speedtest-cli` and you have to change `#!` inside `speedtest-cli`. OR test `python2 /usr/bin/speedtest-cli`

Answer (score 0):

speedtest.py is in fact a python script running speedtest-cli which is another python script.

The solution was to update the first shebang line in the speedtest-cli script to explicitly use python2, then it worked.

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

At times it is not efficient to hardcode a script with a specific interpreter like python2 or python3 as it might not be compatible for different versions and more importantly when a particular version is obsolete. I generally recommend a command line argument like in case of ansible run you can use 'ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3' (python2 in your case) on a command line for smooth flow of a task.

Nevertheless you have a workaround which should be fine I believe.